# How do you resolve the: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

How do you resolve this? Doing some training on Spyder with Python and I think Bitdefender's blocking permissions to let me read Excel files. Does anyone know how to grant permissions?  I keep getting the same FileNotFoundError

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\housing')
print(df)
```

Returns as:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\.spyder-py3\\housing'
```

Comment: I see no extension for the file. May be the file name is something like housing.xls or housing.xlsx , you have to find first the real filename. Most likely you have a setting on widows to not show files extension.

Comment: Why do you have `user\.spyder-py3` in your error message when you have `user.spyder-py3` in the code you've shown?

Answer (score 2):

Include the extension of your file in the path (`.xls` or `.xlsx` etc.)

Comment: You seem to have missed that the OP uses [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#:~:text=Both%20string%20and%20bytes%20literals%20may%20optionally%20be%20prefixed%20with%20a%20letter%20%27r%27%20or%20%27R%27).

Comment: Got my Mistake, Thanks